# Doubts about Boost lexeme[] directive's behavior

Tags: c++, boost

I don't work with C++ but I have a problem wich involve the lexeme directive. I consulted the directive's documentation and I didn't understand this part:

> Keep in mind that lexeme[] pre-skips spaces. If this is not desired, use the no_skip directive instead.

What pre-skips spaces means?

Comment: That means that `lexeme` will apply skipper before the first match by the enclosed parser. `no_skip` doesn't do that. Imagine you parse `   abc   `. Using `+char_` and `space` skipper, result is `abc`. WIth `lexeme[+char_]` it's `abc   `. With `no_skip[+char_]` it's `   abc   `. [Easy to try.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2a2cdb594df3004)

Comment: Exactly what I need to know, by the way, it solved my problem, thanks!